# fatal error: params/params-1.h: No such file or directory

Tags: python, c, parameters

I trying running C program with python. i want to get the NUMBER from one of the param file in params folder: params-example-one , params-example-two, params-example-three. i not sure why the code is not working. i get the error:

```
gcc -Wall -O3 -DPARAMS   -c -o state.o state.c
In file included from state.h:13,
                 from state.c:1:
params.h:4:37: fatal error: params/params-1.h: No such file or directory
    4 | #include xstr(params/params-PARAMS.h)
      |                                     ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [<builtin>: state.o] Error 1
```

i want to choose the the right param file from python code.

the files looks like this:

params-example-one/two/three

```
#ifndef PARAMS_EXAMPLE_H
#define PARAMS_EXAMPLE_H

#define NUMBER 1 //2 or 3 

#endif
```

this is my param.h file:

```
#define str(s) #s
#define xstr(s) str(s)

#include xstr(params/params-PARAMS.h)
```

makefile:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -O3 -DPARAMS$(PARAMS)
LDFLAGS = -lcrypto -lm
OBJFILES = state.o benchmark.o
TARGET = benchmark

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJFILES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJFILES) $(LDFLAGS)
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJFILES) $(TARGET) *~
```

state.c

```
#include "state.h"

void print_number() {
    printf("%d", NUMBER);
}
```

state.h

```
#ifndef STATE_H
#define STATE_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <openssl/rand.h>
#include <openssl/bn.h>
#include <limits.h>

#include "params.h"

void print_number() ;

#endif
```

benchmark.c

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199309L
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "state.h"


int main()
{
    
    print_number();
}
```

benchmark.py

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import fileinput
import itertools
import os
import sys
from subprocess import DEVNULL, run

file_number = ["one"]

paramset = "example-{}".format(file_number[0])

paramfile = "params-{}.h".format(paramset)
print("Benchmarking", paramset, flush=True)
params = 'PARAMS={}'.format(paramset)
run(["make", "clean"], stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=sys.stderr)
run(["make", params], stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=sys.stderr)
run(["./benchmark"],stdout=sys.stdout, stderr=sys.stderr)
print(flush=True)
```

i try to run the code without the benchmark.py and without params-example-one , params-example-two, params-example-three. i just use the param.h with #define NUMBER 1, and its working. but this is not what I expecting. i want to choose the right param file in python code.

Comment: You mean `params.h` not `param.h`, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing an `=` sign in the makefile:

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -O3 -DPARAMS=$(PARAMS)
                         # ^ here
```

The compiler output doesn't correspond to the code you provided though.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i try to change it, but it's still show my the same error: 
```
gcc -Wall -O3 -DPARAMS=   -c -o state.o state.c
In file included from state.h:13,
                 from state.c:1:
params.h:4:37: fatal error: params/params-.h: No such file or directory
    4 | #include xstr(params/params-PARAMS.h)
      |                                     ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [<builtin>: state.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the same code that you posted here? Because this works fine.

Comment: thanks you, yes its working now, but is running only with: ./benchmark.py